# VBA code works in one box, throws an error in another

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Alright, short background, I have a form, on which I have 3 Comboboxes.
Two of these comboboxes are tied to the same exact table, an accounts table. They use slightly different queries between them, see below.

In one box, cmb_GA I have set the box property "On Not in List" to the following code segment :

```
Private Sub cmb_GA_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String
Dim password As String
Dim bytUpdate As Byte

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection


bytUpdate = MsgBox("Do you want to add " & NewData & " to the Accounts list?", vbYesNo, "Not in list of Accounts!")

If bytUpdate = vbYes Then
    password = InputBox("Enter New Account Password")
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Accounts(Login, PW) " & "VALUES 
                      ('" & NewData & "@mcsnet.org' , '" & password & "')"
    Debug.Print strSQL
    cnn.Execute strSQL
    Response = acDataErrAdded
    Call AuditLogs("txt_DN", "New")

ElseIf bytUpdate = vbNo Then

    Response = acDataErrContinue
    Me!cmb_GA.Undo


End If


Exit Sub


ErrHandler:

    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

Note that for formatting here I put in an extra CR after "VALUES" that doesn't exist in the actual  code, other than that, and some deleted comments, WYSIWIG.

This code works perfectly. 100% Does what I want.

I have another combobox, cmb_IA

I am using the same code for it (Yeah I probably should have done this as a module in retrospect, but I didn't yet.)

The problem is that it throws an error. "The text you entered isn't an item in the list. Select an Item from the list, or enter text that matches one of the listed items."

I've looked at the properties and can not find a difference between the two boxes on the property sheets: Here's a look at both boxes Data tab:

[image: cmb_GA Data tab]

[image: cmb_IA Data tab]

And here is the relevant SQL from the two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Accounts
WHERE tbl_Accounts.Association LIKE "*Device*";
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Accounts
WHERE tbl_Accounts.Association LIKE "*Intune*";
```

I would assume the question is obvious, but let me state this outright, what is happening here? Is there a way to suppress this error? Both comboboxes must let the user add new information to them, as the point of this form is to register new devices, cellphones and tablets, and the security accounts and corporate accounts that each device uses. What's puzzling me the most is that this error is only showing up on the one combobox.

Edited to add the code from the section that is throwing the error:

```
Private Sub cmb_IA_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String
Dim password As String
Dim bytUpdate As Byte

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection


bytUpdate = MsgBox("Do you want to add " & NewData & " to the Accounts list?", vbYesNo, "Not in list of Accounts!")

If bytUpdate = vbYes Then
    password = InputBox("Enter New Account Password")
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Accounts(Login, PW) " & "VALUES ('" & NewData & "@mcsnet.org' , '" & password & "')"
    Debug.Print strSQL
    cnn.Execute strSQL
    Response = acDataErrAdded
    Call AuditLogs("txt_DN", "New")

ElseIf bytUpdate = vbNo Then

    Response = acDataErrContinue
    Me!cmb_IA.Undo


End If


Exit Sub


ErrHandler:

    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

It was suggested I show the RowSource SQL generated by Access so here it is Working:

```
SELECT qry_DeviceAccounts.AccountIDKey, qry_DeviceAccounts.Login, qry_DeviceAccounts.PW
FROM qry_DeviceAccounts
ORDER BY qry_DeviceAccounts.[Login];
```

Not  Working:

```
SELECT qry_SecurityAccounts.AccountIDKey, qry_SecurityAccounts.Login, qry_SecurityAccounts.PW
FROM qry_SecurityAccounts
ORDER BY qry_SecurityAccounts.[Login];
```

Comment: Should have posted procedure for combobox that doesn't work, not working code.

Comment: Literally the same code, but sure, I will edit and throw it in place, done, Like I said, probably should have actually been a separate module now that I think more about it, given it will likely be called at least one more time.

Comment: Why are you showing * in query statements? This is not in the RowSource. The RowSource is showing a query as source, not table. Show actual RowSource SQL.

Comment: Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I didn't see it earlier. This was the result of the difference between the two queries, and the way they filtered for the account information. I needed to set the new account information to be filtered for during the INSERT statement, which hadn't been done. Since the other one worked on the default value of one of the fields in the table, it wasn't relevant to that one's INSERT statement.

Moral of the story, check your fields, and make sure you carefully read what each is doing. I was so busy looking for an error in my VBA, I forgot to check my SQL.

Comment: Glad you fixed. Don't think I would use queries as source for comboboxes. I would just reference table and use filter criteria in RowSource SQL.